# unable to run python script through "execute command" using SSH library of ROBOT framework

Tags: python, ssh, robotframework

```
ssh_obj.execute_command('python /tmp/posttoci.py',return_stdout=True, return_stderr=True,return_rc=True)
```

while running through RIDE the following is logged

```
"20140308 21:52:37.106 :  INFO : Executing command 'python /tmp/posttoci.py'.

20140308 21:52:37.224 :  INFO : Command exited with return code 1."
```

I am not able to execute python script in remote machine. Please help.

**Note** : I have successfully logged in into the remote machine using open connection keyword and login keyword of ssh library.

Comment: do you know that python is installed on the remote machine, and that it is on the PATH? Have you tried changing your test to use the fully qualified path to python?

Answer (score 0):

Is that posttoci.py present in the remote machine ?? or your local machine where you started your ssh session ??

If it is in local machine use 'Put File' to copy to target machine and then use 'Execute Command'

```
Open Connection ${IP}
Login ${user} ${password}
SSH Library.Put File    ${source}   /tmp/posttoci.py
Execute Command python /tmp/posttoci.py
```

Comment: The file /tmp/posttoci.py is in remote machine.